# Display returning value of insert_id from function

Tags: php, function, oop

How to display the last inserted id from insert function? It always shows undefined variable in action.php

insert.php

```
class DataOperation extends Database
{       
public function insert_record($table,$fields){
    //"INSERT INTO table_name (, , ) VALUES ('m_name','qty')";
    $sql = "";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $sql .= " (".implode(",", array_keys($fields)).") VALUES ";
    $sql .= "('".implode("','", array_values($fields))."')";
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
    if($query){
        $last_id = $this->con->insert_id;
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

action.php

```
$obj = new DataOperation;
//some $_POST and $myArray
if($obj->insert_record("account",$myArray)){
    echo $last_id;
}else{
     echo "<h1> Error! </h1>";
}
```

Comment: `$last_id` only exists in the function `insert_record`. If you want the id, then return it instead of true. Or assign it to a class variable that you can then get back out either via property or function.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, variables in functions are not accessible outside of function, if you want to access this create class variable `public $lastId = null;` and assign last id to this variable `$this->lastId = $this->con->....`